# Lost Android Studio keystore

Tags: android-studio, keystore

I happen to accidentally delete the keystore I signed my apk with. And my Android Studio 3.2.1 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS also does not give me the option to chose signature versions V1 and V2 while signing the apks. Can a copy of my project be signed with a new keystore and be eligible for the play store? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is not uploaded in the Play store yet, you can generate a new keystore, if your app is already on the Play Store and you don't have the keystore anymore, then you have a problem...you should do a multiple backup of your app Keystore before you upload it to the market, that's an hard lesson to face. Good luck my friend, keep coding!

Comment: Thanks for the response. The app is not uploaded in the play store, fortunately. It was complaining that I did not have the correct signature. If only there was some way to change the signatures maybe? It signs with V2 on default I believe, because, I find that the correct signature is V1 everywhere I search. But now when I sign it with a new key, it says I have signed it with the wrong key.

Comment: Happy to hear that, good luck dude and make multiple backups of your keystore!